# geometry what structure is derived from half a parallelepiped structure

Tags: geometry, determinant, triangles, 3d

the question comes from vector and determinants.

we all know that two 2D vectors v, and w, is a parallelogram. and half this is an triangle.
they can be found by the determinant.

i wanted to extend it to 3D, and there are no problem in that we just find the Volume instead of an area.
the structure is now a parallelepiped structure.
[Parralelepiped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXvIU.png)

but what structure is derived from the half method for finding a triangle, now in 3D.

it became to trigy for me to justify it, since
if one looks at the picture cutting from v to W (their arrows). then this is clear, but do I also need to cut between say u and v, or/and u and w.

another reasoning is cutting in half is equal to half the volume thus we can only cut it ones (do people get this)

and is this cutting the v and w, or one of the other combinations or are this actually not important.

another thing for 2D, 2 variables, we use 1/2 the area for a triangle. should I for 3D 3 variables do 1/3

if any body asking what are you trying to find. i just want to know if taking half the Determinant of a parallelepiped what structure comes.

and if it is not a triangle, and I want a triangle. then should I use 1/3 of the determiant to find its volume for the structure is this doing half of v and w, plus half of u and v, and/or u and w. so we cut 2 times or cur 3 times

lastly if 3D  cutting equivalent of 2D, is this 1/3 of Determinat then is this extended to higher dimensions by R<sup>n</sup> needs 1/n of the determinant

another way of saying it: is if 2d is 1/2, is 3d 1/3, 4d 1/4,...

Comment: That figure is called a tetrahedron. Its volume is $1/6$ of the volume of the parallelepiped. See if this can be of help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3850098/how-is-the-volume-of-a-tetrahedron-one-sixth-that-of-a-parallelepiped-please/3850197#3850197

Comment: What OP is looking for in any number of dimensions, is called the [simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex), whose volume $V$ in $n$ dimensions is $$V = \frac{\lvert \det M \rvert}{n!}$$where $M$ is a matrix where each column represents the coordinates of one of the vertices, but with an additional row at the bottom containing all ones; see e.g. the Wikipedia article on [simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#Volume).

Comment: Intelligenti pauca - you are correct, both of you are correct. ad 3 Dimension is a tetrahedron thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In $N$-dimensional Euclidean space the notion of triangle in 2D generalizes to a [simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex).  In 3D, the simplex is the tetrahedron.

If we have $N+1$ vertices in $N$ dimensions, they form a simple.  If we name the vertices $\vec{v}_0, \vec{v}_1, \dots, \vec{v}_N$, the volume $V$ of the simplex they form is
$$\begin{aligned}
V &= \frac{1}{N!} \left\lvert \det\biggl( \begin{matrix}
(\vec{v}_1 - \vec{v}_0) & (\vec{v}_2 - \vec{v}_0) & \dots & (\vec{v}_N - \vec{v}_0) \end{matrix} \biggr) \right\rvert \\
~ &= \frac{1}{N!} \left\lvert \det\biggl( \begin{matrix}
\vec{v}_0 & \vec{v}_1 & \dots & \vec{v}_N \\
1 & 1 & \dots & 1 \\
\end{matrix} \biggr) \right\rvert \\
\end{aligned}$$
You can use either of the right sides you want, they both will always yield the same result.

Examples:

In 2D, if we have a simplex with vertices $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$, and $(1,0)$, then
its volume is
$$V ~=~ \frac{1}{2!} \left\lvert \det\biggl( \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{matrix} \biggr) \right\rvert ~=~ \frac{1}{2!} \left\lvert \det\left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \end{matrix}\right) \right\rvert ~=~ \frac{1}{2}$$

In 3D, if we have a simplex with vertices $(0,0,0)$, $(0,0,1)$, $(0,1,0)$, and $(1,0,0)$, then its volume is
$$V ~=~ \frac{1}{3!} \left\lvert \det\left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{matrix} \right) \right\rvert
~=~ \frac{1}{3!} \left\lvert \det\left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \end{matrix} \right) \right\rvert
~=~ \frac{1}{6}$$

The generalisation of *parallelogram* and *parallelepiped* is [parallelotope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelepiped#Parallelotope), and its volume is the magnitude of the determinant above, when $\vec{v}_0$ is some vertex, and $\vec{v}_k$ for $k = 1 \dots N$ are the vertices that share an edge with $\vec{v}_0$.  The ratio of their volumes is $1/N!$ in $N$ dimensions.

Comment: thank you this is what i mean, i was nervous no body got, what i asked about.
i am in chemistry and wanted to relate it to crystal shaped, and this is really spot on what you showed me.